# Как заполнить файл массивом?

Tags: c, массивы, файлы

Как поместить в пустой файл двумерный массив из рандомных или вводимых чисел? Какие функции можно для этого использовать в Си?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать функцию [fprintf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm) и в двух циклах пройтись по массиву.

Comment: В двух циклах :)

Comment: @Harry точно! массив двухмерный.